# Extensions of generic types in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I have two protocols and a generic struct:

```
public protocol OneDimensionalDataPoint {
    /// the y value
    var y: Double { get }        
}

public protocol TwoDimensionalDataPoint: OneDimensionalDataPoint {
    /// the x value
    var x: Double { get }
}

public struct DataSet<Element: OneDimensionalDataPoint> {
    /// the entries that this dataset represents
    private var _values: [Element]
    //...implementation
}

extension DataSet: MutableCollection {
    public typealias Element = OneDimensionalDataPoint
    public typealias Index = Int

    public var startIndex: Index {
        return _values.startIndex
    }

    public var endIndex: Index {
        return _values.endIndex
    }

    public func index(after: Index) -> Index {
        return _values.index(after: after)
    }

    public subscript(position: Index) -> Element {
        get{ return _values[position] }
        set{ self._values[position] = newValue }
    }
}
```

There is a large number of methods that apply to `DataSet` only when it's `Element` is a `TwoDimensionalDataPoint`. So I made an extension like so:

```
extension DataSet where Element: TwoDimensionalDataPoint {
    public mutating func calcMinMaxX(entry e: Element) {
        if e.x < _xMin {
            _xMin = e.x
        }
        if e.x > _xMax {
            _xMax = e.x
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't like this, and says:

> Value of type 'DataSet.Element' (aka
>   'OneDimensionalDataPoint') has no member 'x'

Shouldn't this be fine since I constrained Element to `TwoDimensionalDataPoint` in the extension?

Comment: No, Element is of type `OneDimensionalDataPoint`, you can't upcast, only downcast.  You never use `TwoDimensionalDataPoint`

Comment: Perhaps my understanding was wrong. If I change my argument list to accept a `TwoDimensionalDataPoint` instead of an `Element`, it will work AND the method will only be exposed when `Element` is of type `TwoDimensionalDataPoint`?

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying  to filter the contents of DataSet, not DataSet itself?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to filter `_values` on `DataSet`

Comment: ok that is not what your where clause is saying,  you are saying DataSet where `DataSet.Element is = TwoDimensionalDataPoint` (Which always fails but the compiler does not know this)  Then later using a OneDimensionalDataPoint

Comment: maybe you can do `extension DataSet where _values: [TwoDimensionalDataPoint]` ?  I avoid using protocol extensions so I am not 100% on how to work it (I think abstract items should remain abstract lol)

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm upcasting here... `TwoDimensionalDataPoint` inherits from `OneDimensionalDataPoint` which would mean I'm downcasting, no? It makes sense to me that I should be allowed to restrict `Element` in my extension to `TwoDimensionalDataPoint` as `TwoDimensionalDataPoint` can also act as a `OneDimensionalDataPoint`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146972/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-jjatie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I popped it into Xcode I was able to get a better understanding of what was going on,

Your issue is your type alias is overriding your generic type,

Rename your generic name to `T` and assign Element to `T`

```
public typealias Element = T
```

or your typealias like:

```
public typealias DataElement = OneDimensionalDataPoint
```

or just drop the typealias all together.